# Create repository in Mercurial under subdirectory in root

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am using bitbucket for creating repositories for Mercurial.

I've create a repo: https://glukamin@bitbucket.org/glukamin/aw2012merc

Now, I've also committed an empty folder, "asd" in that repo. It has .hgignore in it.
I would like to set my repository in that folder, "asd". 
So, basically it should look like this: https://glukamin@bitbucket.org/glukamin/aw2012merc/asd -> if that is possible, which should be my main repo after setting it.

I am really new to Mercurial and as far as I could understand it, .hg should be created in that folder. I don't know how to do that. I am reading about Mercurial online and trying to understand it better but I need help on this. I am also using Mercurial.NET.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial does not track empty directories and as such they can neither be added nor committed. Are you sure you didn't add in that process the .hgignore within that directory to your main repository?

However: It's easy to create a(nother, new, unrelated) repository within a sub-directory. Just go to that sub-directory and execute `hg init` and you're done; you then have a new repository residing there without any commits to it. It does not affect the repository which might rule the parent directory.

I suggest to read the hg book: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: I did add .hgignore because that is the only way to add an empty dir to repo. Now knowing that it is possible to just do `hg init` in that subdir that's something. I am already reading it. Can you tell me how to add (another, new, unrelated) repository within a sub-directory on bitbucket? I am not sure how to navigate to that subdirectory with Mercurial.NET on bitbucket. Thanks